# Trying to Display a Window Using JFrame but is not Working

Tags: java

I have a Display Class which is supposed to open a window to the console with a specified width and height and on that window there is a canvas. I am running this on Eclipse and just a few days ago the program worked fine and the window opened perfectly, but now it is not and I have not changed anything with the code. I will post my full program though it is a bit lengthy. Basically, I have a Launcher Class which creates an instance of the Game Class called game. Then it calls the Game Class method Start() using game.Start(). This method creates a Thread and executes it with thread.start(). This executes the run() method which calls the init() method which (finally) creates the display and calls the Display Class.

Sorry for making you read all that but I did not want to leave anything out. Another thing that could help discover the problem is that after the run() method creates the display and everything it should run through a loop of tick() and render() infinitely. I have not yet made code to exit the loop, but when I start this program in Eclipse, it terminates almost immediately; shouldn't it run until I manually terminate it?

```
public class Launcher {
  public static void main(String[] args){
    Game game = new Game("This is the title", 400, 400);
    game.start();
  }
}

import dev.codenmore.firstgame.display.Display;

public class Game implements Runnable{

private Display display;

private int width, height;
private String title;
private boolean running = false;

private Thread thread;

public Game(String title, int width, int height){
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    this.title = title;
}

public void init(){
    display = new Display(title, width, height);
}

public void tick(){

}

public void render(){

}
public void run(){
    init();

    while(running){
        tick();
        render();
    }
    stop();
}
public synchronized void start(){
    if (running = true)
        return;

    running = true;
    thread = new Thread(this);
    thread.start();
}
public synchronized void stop(){
    if (!running)
        return;

    running = false;
    try {
        thread.join();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}


import java.awt.Canvas;

import java.awt.Dimension;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Display {

private JFrame frame;
private String title;
private int height, width;

private Canvas canvas;

public Display(String title, int width, int height){
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    this.title = title;

    createDisplay();
}

private void createDisplay(){
    frame = new JFrame(title);
    frame.setSize(width, height);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);


    canvas = new Canvas();
    canvas.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width, height));
    canvas.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(width, height));
    canvas.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(width, height));

    frame.add(canvas);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
  }
}
```

***EDIT***

Realizing my mistake with just pasting all my code on my post, I copy and pasted just my Display Class into a new project and called it and the window opens up perfectly. So the problem must be that the code which calls the Display Class in my program is not being executed?

Comment: `if (running = true)` ?? And all your graphics is on a background thread? Are you following a specific guide or anything or just having a go yourself?

Comment: For better help sooner post a [mcve].

Comment: @John3136 Yes I am following a tutorial. From what I understand that if statement is just a precautionary thing to make sure that a new thread doesn't get executed if there is already one running.

Comment: Here is a link to the tutorial playlist https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLah6faXAgguMnTBs3JnEJY0shAc18XYQZ I am on the fifth video.

Comment: @MasterBlaster Sorry for making it so extensive. I'll make sure to take that advice if I post in the future. This is my first post and I have no idea what the problem is so I just posted it all. But to everyone, I do not think it is a problem with the code itself as I have looked over it extensively for errors.

Answer (score 1):

as @John3136 says

replace

```
 if (running = true)
```

with

```
 if (running == true)
```

in your `start method`

because

```
(running=true)
```

will always return true. And your program will end ahead of  schedule.

Comment: Cannot believe I did not see this before... thank you. So embarrassed...